# responsive grid with minmax() doesn't work when using grid area

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, css-grid

### What i want to achieve

I want to achieve a responsive grid layout with three columns and two rows, where the last column spans two rows and contains an image, as shown below :

[image: text]

Specifically, I want the image to move to the bottom row on tablet devices, and all columns to be displayed in a single column on mobile devices.

#### in tablet :

[image]

#### in mobile:

[image]

### What i try & expect to happen

I've attempted to use `grid-template-area` to arrange the grid items and `minmax()` function to achieve the responsive grid, but my grid is not responsive even if I use `minmax()`. I'd like to achieve this layout without using media queries if possible.

#### The problem

[image: text]

> see : [grid.layoutit](https://grid.layoutit.com/)

#### Understand the problem

I think the problem occurs when using `grid-area` because it determines the position and size of grid children. When combined with `minmax()` and a child's width becomes smaller than **300px**, it does not wrap when resizing the window. This is because `grid-area` defines a fixed position for children in the grid. For example, the first child `.services .service1 { grid-area: 1 / 1; }` is placed in the first row and column.

When the first child `service1`, becomes smaller than **300px** due to `minmax(300px, 1fr)`, it should **wrap** to the second row and column 1, which is contrary to the `grid-area` decision.

So how can i decide the position of all my grid children's and make the grid responsive at the same time? , because i think i can't do this if i combine `minmax()` and `grid-area`

#### Code Snippet

```html
<div class="services container">

        <div class="service1">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-palette fa-2x">
                </i>
                <h4>
                    Graphic Design
                </h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet
                expedita numquam pariatur tempora, praesentium laudantium ad, porro reprehenderit repellat aut
                perspiciatis, unde optio odio ab.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="service2">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-gem fa-2x">
                    </i>
                                <h4>
                    Web Design
                                </h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente harum a illo voluptatum facere
                repudiandae voluptates optio deleniti tenetur vel accusantium sequi minima, odio minus eius veritatis
                obcaecati. Natus, similique?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service3">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-ruler fa-2x"></i>
                <h4>
                    UI and UX
                </h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis culpa minima hic est laborum
                necessitatibus rerum quidem, commodi quas iusto. Odio fuga cum perspiciatis delectus fugit quisquam
                voluptate quos rem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service4">

                <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-2x"></i>
                <h4>
                    Web Development
                </h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, consequatur reiciendis officia
                pariatur culpa nam tempore, dolores rem nesciunt nobis, exercitationem dolorum. Culpa, commodi facere?
                Nihil fugit id expedita laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="image"><img src="assets/images/services.jpg" alt="services"></div>

    </div>
```

```css
.services {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        '. card1 card2 image . '
        '. card3 card4 image . ';
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    row-gap: 2rem;
    align-content: center;
    padding-block: 5rem;
}

.services .service1 {
    grid-area: card1;
}

.services .service3 {
    grid-area: card2;
}

.services .service2 {
    grid-area: card3;
}

.services .service4 {
    grid-area: card4;
}

.services .image {
    position: relative;
    grid-area: image;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.services .image::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #292a2f;
    border: #10cab7 2px solid;
    top: -11%;
    left: 65%;
    width: 167px;
    height: 585px;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* grid children are also displayed with grid */
.services>div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px max-content;
    align-items: start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always find it's easier to manipulate grid with row, column start of each element. It's a bit complicated to visualize at beginning, but check here http://cssgridbuilder.com/. The good thing with that, it's you who decide this element will be from here to here, and at this media it'll be from here to here. You can even overlap elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.services {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.services .service1 {}

.services .service3 {}

.services .service2 {}

.services .service4 {}

.services .image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* grid children are also displayed with grid */

.services .service {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.services .service *:nth-child(1) {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.services .service *:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.services .service *:nth-child(3) {}

@media (min-width: 390px) {}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .services {
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .services .service1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
  .services .service3 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  }
  .services .service2 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  }
  .services .service4 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  }
  .services .image {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 3;
  }
  .services .service {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .services {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding-block: 5rem;
  }
  .services .service1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
  .services .service3 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  }
  .services .service2 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  }
  .services .service4 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  }
  .services .image {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  }
  .services .service {
    column-gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .services .service *:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    align-self: start;
  }
  .services .service *:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .services .service *:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {}
```

```html
<div class="services container">

  <div class="service service1">
    <svg class="expand" style="width: 48px;height: 48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentcolor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M 37,20 V 11 H 28 V 9 h 11 v 11 z"/>
            <path d="M 31,28 V 17 H 20 v -3 h 14 v 14 z"/>
            <path d="M 9,39 V 28 h 2 v 9 h 9 v 2 z"/>
            <path d="M 14,34 V 20 h 3 v 11 h 11 v 3 z"/>
            <rect width="6" height="6" x="21.274239" y="21"/>
        </svg>
    <h4>
      Graphic Design
    </h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Officia, velit? Inventore voluptas quis eveniet expedita numquam pariatur tempora, praesentium laudantium ad, porro reprehenderit repellat aut perspiciatis, unde optio odio ab.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="service service2">
    <svg class="expand" style="width: 48px;height: 48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentcolor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M 37,20 V 11 H 28 V 9 h 11 v 11 z"/>
            <path d="M 31,28 V 17 H 20 v -3 h 14 v 14 z"/>
            <path d="M 9,39 V 28 h 2 v 9 h 9 v 2 z"/>
            <path d="M 14,34 V 20 h 3 v 11 h 11 v 3 z"/>
            <rect width="6" height="6" x="21.274239" y="21"/>
        </svg>
    <h4>
      Web Design
    </h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente harum a illo voluptatum facere repudiandae voluptates optio deleniti tenetur vel accusantium sequi minima, odio minus eius veritatis obcaecati. Natus, similique?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service service3">
    <svg class="expand" style="width: 48px;height: 48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentcolor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M 37,20 V 11 H 28 V 9 h 11 v 11 z"/>
            <path d="M 31,28 V 17 H 20 v -3 h 14 v 14 z"/>
            <path d="M 9,39 V 28 h 2 v 9 h 9 v 2 z"/>
            <path d="M 14,34 V 20 h 3 v 11 h 11 v 3 z"/>
            <rect width="6" height="6" x="21.274239" y="21"/>
        </svg>
    <h4>
      UI and UX
    </h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis culpa minima hic est laborum necessitatibus rerum quidem, commodi quas iusto. Odio fuga cum perspiciatis delectus fugit quisquam voluptate quos rem.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service service4">
    <svg class="expand" style="width: 48px;height: 48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentcolor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M 37,20 V 11 H 28 V 9 h 11 v 11 z"/>
            <path d="M 31,28 V 17 H 20 v -3 h 14 v 14 z"/>
            <path d="M 9,39 V 28 h 2 v 9 h 9 v 2 z"/>
            <path d="M 14,34 V 20 h 3 v 11 h 11 v 3 z"/>
            <rect width="6" height="6" x="21.274239" y="21"/>
        </svg>
    <h4>
      Web Development
    </h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, consequatur reiciendis officia pariatur culpa nam tempore, dolores rem nesciunt nobis, exercitationem dolorum. Culpa, commodi facere? Nihil fugit id expedita laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="services"></div>

</div>
```

Try at diff resolution.
For your image, I think it would be better to put it in background-image

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this not response my question:

> **I'd like to achieve this layout without using media queries if possible.**

i can use the same `media query` snippet you mention with `grid-template-area` but i just want to achieve the **rwd** with just `minmax()` function